# How to configure alternatives for Python?

Tags: linux, installation, python

I am installing python 3.10 without the use of a package manager on Rocky Linux 8 and would like to use `alternatives` version 1.19.1 ([manpage](https://www.mankier.com/8/alternatives)) to manage different versions of python installations in the future.

These are my steps:

0. Install prerequisites `dnf -y install "Development Tools"` (Make sure you also have  `wget`, `openssl-devel`, `bzip2-devel`, `libffi-devel`)
1. Download Python 3.10 from  https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.9/Python-3.10.9.tgz
2. unarchive to `/opt/python`
3. In `/opt/python/Python-3.10.9` run `./configure --enable-optimizations`
4. In `/opt/python/Python-3.10.9` run `make altinstall`
5. Add a group of alternatives where

   - link=`/usr/bin/python`
   - name=`python`
   - path=`/usr/local/bin/python3.10`
   - priority=`50`

`alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/local/bin/python3.10 50`

Now I would like to have `python3` also point to the same thing that `python` would be pointing to. I guess I could create a symlink pointing to `/usr/bin/python`, but I was wondering if I should use `alternatives` in a way I am not understanding right now?
How ca I achieve that?

I tried `alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.10 50`, but this creates a whole new group.

This question makes me realize that maybe `alternatives` focuses only on the 1 to n relations between what the user types (`python`) and what it points to (`python3.10`). rather than a n to n relation. Not sure.